# Show banner in category page sub

Tags: cms

I create cms block and add call in category it show in main cat but not in the sub cat of this main category

```
<?php 
$currentCateId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
///if($currentCateId == 3){
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('aed-left-banner-new')->toHtml(); 
//}
?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: you want to show cms block on product catalog page before the products?

Comment: no in layer navigation but it show on main cateogty which id 3 but now i want to display all sub category of 3

Comment: Are you setting it like my answer?

Comment: no you not getting

Comment: Is it like on subcategories when you used "Static block and products" then it is not showing static block?

Comment: i have cate aed i crete static block and call it for aed category its shows fime but when i clikc on aed's sub category it not showing

Comment: parent categories static block will not show on sub categories until you will add static block in subcategories also. have you added static block in sub categories also?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show static block on catalog page then you don't have to write the custom code you can use default feature of Magento. You can show the blocks in category like the attached image

[image]